# SCP gives error: "Read-only file system"

Tags: 16.04, read-only, scp

Using Ubuntu 16.04, I am having an issue. When I try to transfer a file to a server that I've transferred to in the past (server is Ubuntu 14.04 server), I get an error that reads "Read-only file system". It also outputs the location of my file in a strange manner... instead of "/home/user/Desktop/file" it displays "/home/user//file", even if I try to use the absolute path to transfer... All other commands work, like editing this exact file, creating a new file/directory, deleting a file/directory. What could be causing this?

Comment: Do you 1) have administrative access to the server and 2) does it run Ubuntu? Otherwise there's either 1) nothing you can do except notify an administrator or 2) it's off topic here.